# Transferring from Blob to Cloud Storage

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I've transferred my App-Engine from BlobStorage to Cloud-Storage. This works finde with these Upload-Code:

Upload.py:

```
...
upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload', gs_bucket_name="my-default-bucket")
...
```

my_upload_template.html:

```
...
<form action="{{ upload_url }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
...
```

Upload.py:

```
class UploadBlobHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
  def post(self):
    file_info = self.get_file_infos()[0]
    self.response.out.write(file_info.gs_object_name)

    self.redirect("/download/serve" + file_info.gs_object_name)
```

it worked great. But it's upload not only in the Google Cloud Storage-Bucket. It's uploaded in den Blob Storage too. (Can check when you go to `https://appengine.google.com` and click Blob Viewer.)

Is that the right way? Is it right? Or do I something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly... you're using the Blobstore API to save to your Google Cloud Storage?

If that is what you're doing, then yes you're doing correctly, and yes it will save a copy of your document in the Blobstore.